# In Cypress unable to click on the sub menu before that main menu gets closed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cypress

cypress code:

`cy.xpath("//ul[@class='row']//h2[@class='doormat-heading'][normalize-space()='Credit Cards']").contains('Credit Cards').trigger('mouseenter')`

HTML:

```
<a href="/credit-cards/" class="doormat-heading-link" tabindex="-1">
        <h2 class="doormat-heading">Credit Cards</h2></a>
```

Answer (score 4):

The documentation shows `.trigger('mouseover')` is the event to use, but only if the popup menu is implemented in Javascript.

Please also try the code shown here: [hover - Invoke/Force](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/hover#Invoke)

> **Force click**
> You can also force the action to be performed on the element regardless of whether the element is visible or not.

```js
cy.get('.hidden').invoke('show').click({force:true})
```

This should work if your menu is implemented in Javascript or in CSS.